# Unable to post image from Android device camera using HttpClient

Tags: android, post, httpclient, android-camera

I'm attempting to post an image taken by the camera on an Android device and some other parameters, using the Apache Commons HttpClient.

My post request works properly, and the parameters are read fine by the server, but my image does not upload.  The upload is handled by a PHP script and I can confirm that a proper HTTP Post will result in an image being successfully uploaded, as I've tested the PHP script using an HTML form. I can also confirm that photo != null in the code below.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/upload.php");
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

if (photo != null) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "submission-1.jpg");

    reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);
}

reqEntity.addPart("date", new StringBody(date));
reqEntity.addPart("lat", new StringBody(latitude));
reqEntity.addPart("long", new StringBody(longitude));
reqEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(name));
reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email));
reqEntity.addPart("comments", new StringBody(comments));

postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: check if byte[] data has something?

Comment: I just verified that it does contain data

Comment: @PeterWillsey: I face same problem . but  I am not getting MultipartEntity  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, hopefully someone else will find this helpful.  All I had to do was add the file type to this line:

```
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image/jpeg", "submission.jpg");
```